# laravel validation 5.1 with authenticated user

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

Im trying to do some validation on my registration form in my `validator` method. I'm concatenating `$user->id` to my `name` & `email` array keys so users cant register with the same name & email address thats already taken.

my `AuthController` below

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {

        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|regex:/^[a-zA-Z]+$/u|max:255|unique:users,name,'.$user->id,
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users'.$user->id,
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        ]);
    }

}
```

every time i hit submit i get a `Undefined variable: user` error message so i try to add `$user = Auth::user();` above my validator method like this

```
    // retrieve authenticated user
    $user = Auth::user();
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {

        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|regex:/^[a-zA-Z]+$/u|max:255|unique:users,name,'.$user->id,
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users'.$user->id,
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        ]);
    }
```

but i get a `syntax error, unexpected '$user'` error message. I'm not sure what I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are creating new User at the time you do not have any `$user` object and certainly you will get get a `Undefined variable: user` error message.

Your validation will work only for updating User profile.

There is a syntax error in you code. Here is the correct one:

```
 return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|regex:/^[a-zA-Z]+$/u|max:255|unique:users,name',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users,email',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ]);
```

Comment: so how can i validate duplicate names and email address during registration with laravel? can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: You want to make a row unique with name & email? if its true then you should not use $user->id

Comment: i think thats what im trying to accomplish. say for example a user signs up with the name `foo` and email `foo@foo.com` i dont want anyone else signing up with those same credentials

Comment: When you insert data into users table, Validator check is there exist any name and email that you have entered. Here we do not need $user->id.

Comment: is there documentation from laravel on this?

Comment: Please have a look: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#available-validation-rules thanks for your interest.